# What does it mean to say "Instance variables are not over-rided" in java?

Tags: java, member-hiding

I am aware of the concept called `field hiding` in java. But still I am having a confusion in relation to instance variable being not over-ridden.

According to my present knowledge, overriding a method of super-class means that the JVM will call the sub-class's over-ridden method though the super-class's method is available to the sub-class.

And I read the similar thing for `field hiding` via the link:- [Hiding Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/hidevariables.html)

So, in any case we are over-ridding the instance if we change the values of the inherited instance variable in the sub-class.

I am confused please help.

---

I am using the following super-class:-

```
public class Animal{
File picture;
String food;
int hunger;
int width, height;
int xcoord, ycoord;

public void makeNoise(){
.........
}

public void eat(){
.............
}

public void sleep(){
..........
}

public void roam(){
.............
}
```

}

It has sub-classes like Tiger, cat, dog,hippo etc.  The sub-classes over-ride the makeNoise(), eat and roam() method.

But each sub-class also uses a different set of values for instance variables.

So as per my confusion, I am kind-of overriding  all the instance variables and 3 methods of the super-class Animal; and I still have the super-class instance variables available to the sub-class with the use of the `super` keyword.

Comment: Please show us some code so we can understand what you are doing

Comment: Did you mean to say **overriding** instead of **overloading**? (Those are two different things).

Comment: yes sir, I am talking about overriding and not overloading.

Comment: Then the title of your question is wrong because it says "overloading".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means if you call a method in a superclass it will resolve to the overriden version in a subclass (if your instance is a subclass). However a reference to a member variable will be bound to the declaration of that variable in the class from which the call is made.

Answer (score 1):

Well, [overloading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading) generally refers to *function/method overloading* that

> allows creating several methods with the same name which differ from
>   each other in the type of the input and the output of the function. It
>   is simply defined as the ability of one function to perform different
>   tasks.

You see, the term relates to functions/methods - not instance variables (fields). The latter cannot be overloaded nor overridden. See e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427756/overriding-a-super-class-instance-variables?rq=1).

With respect to your example: actually, you are not *overriding* the ancestor's fields but *hiding* them.

An example:

```
class Human {
    String name;
    int age;

    public Human(String n, int a) {
        this.name = n;
        this.age = a;
    }

    public void tell_age() {
        System.out.println("I am "+this.age);
    }
}

class Female extends Human {
    // We want to HIDE our real age ^^
    String age = 'not too old';

    public Female(String n, int a) {
        this.name = n;
        super.age = a;
    }

    // We override the parent's method to cloak our real age,
    // without this, we would have to tell our true age
    public void tell_age() {
        System.out.println("I am "+this.age);
    }

    // Ok, we give in, if you really need to know
    public void tell_true_age() {
        System.out.println("I am "+super.age);
    }
}
```

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Female Jenna = new Female('Jenna', 39);

    Jenna.tell_age(); // => I am not too old
    Jenna.tell_true_age(); // I am 39
}
```

Comment: yes i have read hiding, (Within a class, a field that has the same name as a field in the superclass hides the superclass's field, even if their types are different).     But my confusion is that like we change the definition of the method(over-riding) in sub-class we can also change the value of the instance variables; then why it's said the instance variables are not over-riden.

Comment: Oh, ok, you've got a problem with the word *overridden*. Sure, in layman's terms one could say that the fields are being overriden by the arguments you pass to the instance's methods; their value is being changed after all. But the term *overriding* in a programmatic sense is being used to refer to a feature in polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

In general, we use `override` to describe the methods but not fields. But you would say they have similar behaviors.

- when they have the same field name/method signature
- the subclass one will always override the superclass one unless you use `super`.